# How can I pull HTML block from a external location and render it with Razor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there anyway I can do the following code in razor?

```
<div>
   <c:import url="http://hostName/HTML-file-name/" />
</div>
```

I would like to pull HTML from a given location and render it on a page. This should be possible...

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: It's mandatory to render the html from the view? because you can render this from the `controller`

Comment: Hi, we are using razor, so ideally I wanted to do it via that...

Answer (score 3):

In Razor, no. In HTML yes:

```
<div>
    <iframe src="http://hostName/HTML-file-name/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Well actually you could use server side code to send an HTTP request to the remote resource and display the result inline:

```
<div>
    @Html.Raw(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://hostName/HTML-file-name/"))
</div>
```

But bear in mind that this will fetch only the content situated on the specified address. If this is for example an HTML page referencing external CSS, and javascript files, they will not be retrieved.

Comment: Also, that should happen in the controller.

Comment: Thank you, Darin! I'll try this and update this question accordingly.